# CPFT_SMALL_TEXT value cant modified after initialize in Windows 7 Credential Provider DLL?

Tags: c++, windows-7, credential-providers

i am modifying credential provider dll in windows 7.

In that dll, i try to add a Small text field and set a value.

it works fine using the below code.

```
hr = SHStrDupA("Bala", &_rgFieldStrings[SFI_I_WORK_IN_STATIC]);
```

after that i want to change the text value in a particular condition,like below.

```
hr = SHStrDupA("Goto other Logon", &_rgFieldStrings[SFI_I_WORK_IN_STATIC]);
```

But it not works.How to resolve that?

Comment: What is `hr`'s value after the second call? Is it `S_OK`?

Comment: `hr`'s value can't be `null` -- isn't it a `DWORD`?